# This site can’t be reached ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED on all websites hosted in IIS

Tags: iis, windows-10, iis-10

These websites were working before and suddenly after a restart of my AWS Workspaces these websites are returning below error on all browsers. I have re-installed IIS and also deleted the files from C:\inetpub\history. When i run the same website from Visual Studio it works but the url would be like http://localhost:29740.

**This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://localhost/xxx might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED**

Answer (score 1):

Are you using chrome browser? there are many reasons for this error, such as the website or service you are trying to access does not support the SSLv3 protocol (Secure Socket Layer Version 3 Protocol), some third-party program like your antivirus or an extension install on to your browser might be interrupting your connection to the website.

Before trying any fixes, try to access the same website from a different browser and preferably a different connection. Try to access the website from the browser in Incognito mode may help too. But if you still encounter this error, here is what you can do to fix it.

1. Disable SSLv3 in Google Chrome:

   First, add a Chrome shortcut to the desktop, then right-click the Chrome desktop shortcut, select Properties, and click the Shortcut tab as below.

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe” –ssl-version-min=tls1`
2. Disable Antivirus and Firewall

   In the System tray on the right corner of your taskbar, right-click on the icon of your Antivirus and then click on the option that refers to disabling your antivirus protection temporarily.If prompted, set the duration of antivirus to be disabled as per your choice.You may temporarily disable Windows Defender in you use iton Windows 10.
   Now, you can check if your issue is resolved or not. Additionally, you can disable your Windows Firewall protection too. This is due to the fact that the Windows Firewall monitors and authorizes or denies and inward or outward connection from your computer.
   Now, you can check again if your issue is resolved or not.
3. Reset Google Chrome

   To reset Chrome browser, make sure that Google Chrome is not running anywhere in the background using the Task Manager.Now, hit the WINKEY + R combinations to  open Run and then navigate to the following path,

   `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

   Now, select the folder named as Default and hit the Shift + Delete button combinations and then click on Yes for the confirmation prompt you get.

   After deleting the Default folder, open Google Chrome and click on the Menu button denoted by three verticle dots in the top right corner.Then, click on Settings. In the Settings section, scroll down and click on Advanced to reveal the Advanced Settings.
   Now, scroll down to the Restore Settings to their original defaults button and click on it.Click on Reset, and this will reset your Google Chrome browser.Now check if you issue is fixed or not.
4. Reinstall Google Chrome

   If all the methods that are mentioned above do not work properly, the last and the ultimate fix would be reinstalling Google Chrome.

Comment: this is happening on all the browsers but still I tried on Chrome and its still the same

Comment: checked the host file and i see a line 127.0.0.1 corresponding to localhost and when i launched the site with url as http://127.0.0.1/xyz it was working fine